# How to create functions that affect only a specific user

Tags: customization, admin, wp-admin, users

I am customizing the WP admin area and want the functions I am using to only affect a specific user. Any Ideas on how to write this?

Answer (score 0):

```
get_currentuserinfo();
if ( $current_user->ID === <ID of user to isolate>) {
   // user specific code
}
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo

That is a very general solution. There may be other/better solutions but you didn't provide much information about what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php get_currentuserinfo(); ?>
```

Then check if the returned value for $current_user->ID is the ID of the user you want and then display the content for that user only?

[See the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo)